# Dialogflow reading response stream

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am using the Dialogflow v2 client library for c# to send a streaming detect intent request. I am struggling to read the response stream.

With the following code, I get this response:

```
IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingDetectIntentResponse> responseStream = duplexStream.ResponseStream;
while (await responseStream.MoveNext())
{
    StreamingDetectIntentResponse response = responseStream.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}


//Response
...
{ "recognitionResult": { "messageType": "TRANSCRIPT", "transcript": "sometime next week" } }
{ "recognitionResult": { "messageType": "END_OF_SINGLE_UTTERANCE" } }
{ "recognitionResult": { "messageType": "TRANSCRIPT", "transcript": "sometime next week", "isFinal": true, "confidence": 0.888456166 } }
Exception thrown: 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' in mscorlib.dll
{ "responseId": "...", "queryResult": {...}}//truncated
```

I assume the above error is due to me not writing complete async once Single Utterance is true. I tried to resolve this with the following code, and get the following errors:

```
IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingDetectIntentResponse> responseStream = duplexStream.ResponseStream;
while (await responseStream.MoveNext())
{
    StreamingDetectIntentResponse response = responseStream.Current;
    Console.WriteLine(response);
    if (response.RecognitionResult.MessageType == StreamingRecognitionResult.Types.MessageType.EndOfSingleUtterance)
    {
        await duplexStream.WriteCompleteAsync();
        done = true;

        Console.WriteLine("A single utterance has been spoken");
    }
}

//Response
...
{ "recognitionResult": { "messageType": "TRANSCRIPT", "transcript": "sometime next week" } }
{ "recognitionResult": { "messageType": "END_OF_SINGLE_UTTERANCE" } }
A single utterance has been spoken
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.dll
{ "recognitionResult": { "messageType": "TRANSCRIPT", "transcript": "sometime next week", "isFinal": true, "confidence": 0.892199934 } }
{ "responseId": "...", "queryResult": {...}}//truncated
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in myconsoleapp.exe
```

**Exception** for `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.dll` is `Cannot call WriteAsync after WriteCompleteAsync`

**Exception** for `'System.NullReferenceException'` is `Reference not set to an instance of an object at line: if (response.RecognitionResult.MessageType == StreamingRecognitionResult.Types.MessageType.EndOfSingleUtterance)`

All of this is in my console application that replicates my actual application, I am hoping that fixing these problems will enable me to directly fix my actual application. The rest of the code is:

```
public async Task StreamingDetectIntent()
{
    bool done = false;
    SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.Create();
    SessionsClient.StreamingDetectIntentStream duplexStream = sessionsClient.StreamingDetectIntent();
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        //See above snippets for the code in this section. This section appears to be causing the errors
    });

    while (!done)
    {
        StreamingDetectIntentRequest request = new StreamingDetectIntentRequest
        {
            Session = new SessionName("telebot-pianomoves-v1", "iq3464rfdw").ToString(),
            SingleUtterance = true,
            QueryInput = new QueryInput() {
                AudioConfig = new InputAudioConfig()
                {
                    AudioEncoding = Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                    SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                    LanguageCode = "en-US",
                },
            },
        };
        await duplexStream.WriteAsync(request);
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\hjstu\Desktop\Telebot\shortrecording.wav");
        Array.Copy(bytes, 44, bytes, 0, bytes.Length - 44);
        foreach (var batch in AsBatches(bytes, 320))
        {
            await duplexStream.WriteAsync(new StreamingDetectIntentRequest()
            {
                InputAudio = Google.Protobuf.ByteString.CopyFrom(batch)
            });
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(17);
        }
    }
}
public static IEnumerable<T[]> AsBatches<T>(T[] input, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0, r = input.Length; r >= n; r -= n, i += n)
    {
        var result = new T[n];
        Array.Copy(input, i, result, 0, n);
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what *does* happen? Does `MoveNext` never return? does it return false? Does it return true, but you're not seeing anything in `streamingCall.ResponseStream.Current`? Could you show how you're writing the request as well?

Comment: I am only receiving the recognition result in the response stream. StreamingCall.ResponseStream.Current type is never a query result. It seems like I am therefore, simply not receiving the query result in this response stream

Comment: Okay... and then does `MoveNext` return false? Or does the task never complete?

Comment: Any code after the while loop is not executed, so I think it is waiting to receive the next element, but it is never received?

Comment: Okay - and just to check, you *definitely* aren't throwing an exception? (I could easily imagine you'd see exactly these symptoms if your loop were throwing an exception that somehow you weren't seeing.) I'd add copious logging to check all of this. If you can reproduce this in a short but complete example, that would be ideal.

Comment: I have implemented try and catch statements pretty much everywhere and no exception seems to be getting thrown. I am receiving a "200 OK" status code from the API and the Dialogflow console says that I have been making successful requests.

Comment: Maybe my issue is with the request? I have attached the code above

Comment: That's definitely helpful, but it would be even better if you could present a single console application that simply sent a single message and dumped the results to the console. I'll see if I can reproduce it with the snippets you've given though.

Comment: Thanks! See the above update. My actual application is hosted on Kubernetes Engine if that helps at all. I have followed the docs so I am quite confused as to where the problem is.

Comment: You've updated the question with a more complete example - but am I right in saying that's one that *doesn't* demonstrate the problem? Have you tried creating a console app that uses the streaming API so that it *can* reproduce the problem? I doubt that using GKE is the issue here. I'm going to try to reproduce this this afternoon. Do you have a sample file we could use?

Comment: I understand what you’re saying, I just wanted to confirm that credentials/sessionname/creating client etc were not the issue. I will work on a console app now with an audio file. The audio file has been added to the question.

Comment: I have narrowed down the code that seems to be causing the errors. I think I am not writing complete async correctly from within the response handling `Task`. See the completely revised question.

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong without the messages for either the RpcException or the InvalidOperationException. Could you edit those in please? (I've edited your question to format the code more usefully - it would be great if you could do the same if you add any more code. It's mostly a matter of making sure everything is outdented as much as it should be.)

Comment: How do I catch the value of the exception, I am simply reading what is in the output window. I have tried using a catch statement but don't seem to be catching the RpcException. Would you by any chance be able to edit them into the question and then I can take that and run the code? Thanks

Comment: You could either run it in debug mode and look at the details of the exception, or you should be able to catch the RpcException. (Or just catch *all* exceptions, and print them out.)

Comment: I caught the null reference exception and am currently trying to figure out how to catch the RpcException. See above

Comment: Right, you'll get an NRE if either `response` or `response.RecognitionResult` is null.

Comment: Well I expect the latter, that is quite fixable but I am struggling to catch `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.dll`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help much without seeing how you're trying to catch it. As I say, you should be able to catch it in the debugger. I would definitely focus on this for the moment - it's **critical** that you're able to see exception information fully.

Comment: Because the exception is in `Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.dll` not my executable, will I have to debug from within `Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.dll`?

Comment: I just had to break on exception, details above. I don't understand why I am getting this though because I am stopping the loop with `done = true`?

Comment: Your `StreamingDetectIntent` method has a local `done` variable - it's not using whichever one is being set in whichever method is setting `done` to true. There are also threading issues here - there's no guarantee that you'll get a response at a convenient time when you're between writes. I'd suggest doing *all* of the writing, including the WriteCompleteAsync, from the same thread. That will make it much easier to ensure you don't call Write again after WriteComplete.

Comment: I get the following erro occasionally: `System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()System.InvalidOperationException: Queue is full`. Would that also be due to threading issues?

Comment: That suggests you're creating too many tasks, yes. But at this point we're really a long way beyond how Stack Overflow is intended to be used, particularly in terms of comments. I suspect it might be best to delete this question now - or edit it so that it makes more complete sense from the start, and we can delete the comments.